# Insert directory path of images in a table with FK [MySQL]

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I'm trying to insert directory path of images in a table with FK (MySQL) using **PHP-PDO**, but I'm receiving this error:

- SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1452 Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`bd-veiculos`.`fotos`, CONSTRAINT `fk_fotos_veiculos` FOREIGN KEY (`veiculos_idveiculos`) REFERENCES `mydb`.`veiculos` (`idveiculos`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION)

This is my table:
[image]

I'm building a CRUD in php, I've got a table with informations of cars as below:
[image]

I've got a submit button called 'AddImages' When I click it, I'm sending via POST the ID of car that I want to change, this is the php page that I send...

uploadimageform.php:
[image]

after that I choose some images then I click submit and send the informations to the next php code:

```
    <?php
    include "dbconfig.php";
    if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
        $id = trim(strip_tags($_POST['id']));

        # INFO IMAGEM
        $file       = $_FILES['img'];
        $numFile    = count(array_filter($file['name']));

        # PASTA
        $folder     = 'uploads';

        # REQUISITOS
        $permite    = array('image/jpeg', 'image/png');
        $maxSize    = 1024 * 1024 * 5;

        # MENSAGENS
        $msg        = array();
        $errorMsg   = array(
            1 => 'O arquivo no upload é maior do que o limite definido em upload_max_filesize no php.ini.',
            2 => 'O arquivo ultrapassa o limite de tamanho em MAX_FILE_SIZE que foi especificado no formulário HTML',
            3 => 'o upload do arquivo foi feito parcialmente',
            4 => 'Não foi feito o upload do arquivo'
        );

        if($numFile <= 0)
            echo 'Selecione uma Imagem!';
        else{
            for($i = 0; $i < $numFile; $i++){
                $name   = $file['name'][$i];
                $type   = $file['type'][$i];
                $size   = $file['size'][$i];
                $error  = $file['error'][$i];
                $tmp    = $file['tmp_name'][$i];

                $extensao = @end(explode('.', $name));
                $novoNome = rand().".$extensao";

                if($error != 0)
                    $msg[] = "<b>$name :</b> ".$errorMsg[$error];
                else if(!in_array($type, $permite))
                    $msg[] = "<b>$name :</b> Erro imagem não suportada!";
                else if($size > $maxSize)
                    $msg[] = "<b>$name :</b> Erro imagem ultrapassa o limite de 5MB";
                else{

                    if(move_uploaded_file($tmp, $folder.'/'.$novoNome)):
                        $msg[] = "<b>$name :</b> Upload Realizado com Sucesso!";
                        $imgpath[] = $folder.'/'.$novoNome;
                        else:
                            $msg[] = "<b>$name :</b> Desculpe! Ocorreu um erro...";
                    endif;
                }

                foreach($msg as $pop)
                    echo $pop.'<br>';
            }
        }
        try
        {
            $sql = "INSERT INTO fotos (tbl_imagecar) VALUES ";

            foreach ($imgpath as $path)
            {
                $sql .= " ('$path'),";
            }

            $sql = substr ($sql,0,strlen ($sql)-1);
            $result = $DB_con->exec($sql);
            echo "Dados criados com sucesso.<br><br>";
        }

        catch(PDOException $e)
        {
            echo $e->getMessage();
        }
    }
?>
<br><br>
<a href="index.php" title="">INDEX</a>
<a href="read.php" title""=>LISTAR</a>
```

Here's the query that I'm trying use to put the informations in the DB:

```
INSERT INTO fotos SET `tbl_imagecar` = 'uploads/19350.JPG', `veiculos_idveiculos` = (SELECT idveiculos FROM veiculos WHERE idveiculos = 3
```

from there I can not progress in my code. (Sorry for my bad English)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are getting database foreign key voilation error. To fix this 
Your field

`mydb.veiculos (idveiculos)`

needs to be first inserted/updated with same value(for example 13232) ,
which you are trying to insert into table field

`bd-veiculos.fotos.veiculos_idveiculos`

Comment: Thanks, your suggestion solve fix my problem, I just changed REFERENCES to mydb.veiculos (idveiculos) to bd-veiculos.veiculos and solved.